# Where is there a treatment of double field theory other than in local coordinates?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, topological-quantum-field-theory, string-theory

The n-lab seems to lack a treatment of double field theory. Where is there a treatment other than in local coordinates? Or at least one which identifies the coordinates as local coordinates for a specified global object?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1907v2.pdf is not to your liking?

Comment: Thanks, Carlo   I was unaware of that paper. I don't subscribe to hep-th; wish cross-referencing were more common. Have also discovered Vaisman's 1203.0836

Comment: Now there is http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3601